# Stuck on refactoring Node/Mongo code from callback functions to Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, es6-promise

I wrote a project in node.js, in which asynchrony is achieved via callback functions. However, I have subsequently learnt about Promises, and async/await. Would it be best practice to refactor project code so that I replace all callback functions with async/await?

Anyway, as a training exercise to myself, I have decided to refactor first to Promises, then to async/await. However, I have some questions about refactoring to promises.

Now, the following example does not really contain much in the way of 'callback hell' so you may think refactoring to promises is not really necessary, but I am deliberately starting with a straight-forward example. Other parts of my code do contain callback hell.

So here is an example of a callback function used in a project of mine. When a user selects one of their blogposts and clicks on 'delete', the following code runs (BlogPost is the database collection)

```
app.post('/users/login', =(req, res)=>{
    BlogPost.findByIdAndDelete(req.body.idOfPostToBeDeleted, (err, blogpost)=>{
    res.redirect('/');
    console.log(err, blogpost)  
    });
});
```

So far, I have refactored it like this.

```
app.post('/users/login', (req,res)=>{
    BlogPost
      .findByIdAndDelete(req.body.idOfPostToBeDeleted)
        .then(
        ()=>{res.redirect('/')})
        .catch((error)=>{console.log(error)})
      ;
      }
```

It seems to work as intended but I feel I haven't done it properly, mainly as I have not created a Promise constructor. All tutorials on this include promise constructors

Why is this working without a promise constructor?

What happens to 'then' keyword if it does not have a promise constructor?

What is best practice here?

Should I create a promise constructor? What would be the code for that look like exactly?

Comment: What does the code for `BlogPost.findByIdAndDelete` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think findByIdAndDelete is intelligent enough to return a Promise if you don't specify a callback.

This is why you don't need to construct a Promise. I think your approach is OK.

Most people would prefer for readability to write this with async await as:

```
app.post('/users/login', (req,res)=> {
  async (req,res)=>{
    try{
      const result = await BlogPost.findByIdAndDelete(req.body.idOfPostToBeDeleted)
      res.redirect('/')
    } catch(e)
    {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```